# "... algorithm follows at most lg N pointers to determine..." What does lg stand for?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

In the statement *"The weighted quick-union algorithm follows at most lg N pointers to determine whether two of N objects are connected"* what does lg stand for?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`lg N` stands for the logarithm of `N`. It is common in computing to use `lg` (in contrast to `log`) to explicitly mean the base-2 logarithm, but that's not universal.

Comment: if its big-O notation then the logartihm base is a constant which is irrelavent anyway

Comment: But there's no big-O visible in the statement, and it is not too unlikely that `lg N` could actually be the upper bound without any constant factors.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure your source says "1g N"? Because that looks more like "lg N" == "log N" to me... You might want to read up on the Disjoint-Set data structure, especially the part with path compression (always having a direct pointer to the head) and ranking (saving the weight/size/rank of a set) . (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure)

Hope this helps.

Comment: seems like someone was faster.